# SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged is not working in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged is not working in UWP.. is there any alternative in UWP?

```
SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged += OnPowerChange;

private void OnPowerChange(object s, PowerModeChangedEventArgs e) 
{
    switch ( e.Mode ) 
    {
        case PowerModes.Resume: 
        break;
        case PowerModes.Suspend:
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not really, it isn't a reliable event anyway.  Especially in a UWP app, it  would be likely be suspended when that event occurs.  What's practical is covered by the [Windows.System.Power namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.power).  A UWP app needs to assume that power can be lost any time after it gets the Suspending event.

Comment: @HansPassant in this Power i am not getting any event related to power like my system goes in sleep or wake..

Comment: @AnkurTripathi It's not the event. It's the suspending event which you should handle to save your content in a UWP app. What do you want to do by detect the system sleep and wake?

Comment: yes, I want to detect sleep and wake event...